# PowerShellの連想配列を関数の戻り値として返せない

Tags: powershell

PowerShellで色々処理をしてくれるGUIを作成しています。
数ある処理の中で連想配列を必要とする箇所があるため、連想配列を作成する関数を一旦挟み、戻り値としてそれを返すという処理をおこなっています。しかし戻り値として返す段階で手詰まりの状態です。
関係するコードのみ簡単にかくと下記となります。

```
# 連想配列作成
Function makeHashTable{
    Param(
        param1,
        param2
    )
    $HashTable = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String, PSObject]]::new()
    for($iをインデックス番号でまわす){
        $value = @()
        foreach($v in $values){
            $str = 略
            $value += $str
        }
        $HashTable.Add($List[$i], $value)
    }
    # １
    return $HashTable
}

# ボタン2の処理
Function Calc{
    Param(
        $HashTable
    )
    # ３
    $HashTableを使った処理
}

略
# 連想配列作成ボタン
$Button1 = 略
$Button1.Add_Click({makeHashTable param1 param2})

# 連想配列を渡すボタン
$Button2 = 略
$Button2.Add_Click({Calc $HashTable}) # ２
```

ボタン１をクリックすると連想配列が作成され、ボタン２をクリックするとその連想配列を使って処理をおこなうというながれです。
私が試したことは、問題なく実行されるかどうかを１、２、３の部分にWrite-Hostを加えて連想配列を呼び出してみたことです（３についてはCalc $HashTableをWrite-Host $HashTableに書き換えました）。
結果は、
１について　連想配列が作成されている
２について　連想配列が作成されていない（$HashTable.Countは0）
３について　２と同じ
でした。
以上からmakeHashTableの戻り値として返ってきていないかと思うのですがこれはなぜでしょうか。
また、どのように修正すべきでしょうか。
ご助言よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> makeHashTableの戻り値として返ってきていないかと思うのですがこれはなぜでしょうか。

返ってきてはいますが受け取るコードがありません。

根本的には[変数のスコープについて](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.3)理解していただくのがいいと思います。

その上で、関数の外側、 `$Button1` や `$Button2` と同じスコープで `$HashTable` を定義するのが無難に思います。

```
# 連想配列作成
Function makeHashTable{
    Param(
        param1,
        param2
    )
    for($iをインデックス番号でまわす){
        $value = @()
        foreach($v in $values){
            $str = 略
            $value += $str
        }
        $HashTable.Add($List[$i], $value)
    }
}

# ボタン2の処理
Function Calc{
    $HashTableを使った処理
}

略

# ここで連想配列を作成する
$HashTable = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String, PSObject]]::new()

# 連想配列作成ボタン
$Button1 = 略
$Button1.Add_Click({makeHashTable param1 param2})

# 連想配列を渡すボタン
$Button2 = 略
$Button2.Add_Click({Calc})
```

こうなっていれば、 `makeHashTable` `Calc` 双方から参照可能です。

Comment: 早速の回答ありがとうございます。お聞きしたい点がございます。現在、設定したリストボックス内にある文字列をButton1で連想配列にするという内容で作成しています。仮に新たに文字列を追加或いは全て入れ直してButton1で連想配列を作成するならば、上記の方法ではkeyが更新されるかkeyが重複すると思います。Button1のクリックで何度も新しいHashTableを作成できるようにしたい場合はどうするべきなのでしょうか。私としてはやはり関数内で作成して渡すというやり方がわかりやすいのですが、リンク先の内容を確認する限り、恐らく変数$HashTableは関数内で生成されるがそれは関数内のみ有効で外側からはみえないという話なので難しそうです...。良い方法ご存知でしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: @manatsu 良い質問ですので答えたいと思いますが、本件とは全く別の内容と思われますので、本件を解決済みとしたのち、別質問として投稿してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。早速新たな質問にさせていただきました。よろしくお願いいたします。